# MVC Routes with/without actions and with/without id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an asp.net MVC site and i would like to go to a controller without an action, but i would also like to be able to give an action on the same or other controllers.

So lets say i have Page.

I would like to be able to access the following urls

MY_URL (nothing else) - This would get another page with id = 1, or name = Home (business logic doesnt matter)
MY_URL/Page/id - This will get a page with a particular Id
MY_URL/Page/Create - Create a new page
MY_URL/Page/Delete - Delete a page
MY_URL/Page/Edit - Edit a page

I thought this would do it, but Create/Delete/Edit dont work (they just go to MY_URL/page with no id)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "Page/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is my controller

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    private PageService _service;

    public PageController(PageService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id)
    {
        ... code to get page if id <> null
        ... code to get home page id id = null

        // return view
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ... Delete, Edit methods implemented
}
```

Any help would be appreciated